# What are these brown spots on my sweet peppers (fruit)?

Tags: diseases, peppers

This has just happened in the past two days. I accidentally smeared wet dirt on them while tending, but surely this isn't a result of that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be blossom end rot. Typically linked to calcium deficiencies in soil and/or irregular watering.